# How to implement Sequential loop in Redux Saga

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to implement a loop that calls another saga in a loop using Redux-saga.
I **don't** want it to be parallels so i **don't** want to use `yield all`.

```
limits.forEach((limit) => yield call(setupLimit, accountId, limit));
```

Here my limits is an array of limit and i need to call an API (which is handled the function* setupLimit).

I also need to pass two arguments to this setupLimit which are accountId and the limit.

I do not succeed to run it. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
for(const limit of limits) {
    yield call(setupLimit, accountId, limit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems obvious, but i didn't find answer anywhere. And ForEach or Map did not work